# Turn off "Starting HTTP Client" from neo4j JDBC with logback/slf4j

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, httpclient, logback

I'm using neo4j-jdbc in an application and get a lot of "*Starting the Apache HTTP client*" messages during connections.

For logging I'm using logback, slf4j and the bridges like jul-to-slf4j, jcl-over-slf4j and log4j-over-slf4j.

My configuration file is in the classpath and called logback.xml. If I set the root log level to "OFF" its working for every message beside the apache messages.

How can I turn off the "Starting the Apache HTTP client" output?
I tried using log4j which also did'nt work for that message.

Setting the specific package of the httpclient (wire, org.apache, org.restlet, etc.) also didn't work.

The output is generated via a getLogger call from org.restlet.ext.httpclient, so no direct System.out.println statement or something like that.

Any thoughts on that?

Edit: These are the relevant dependencies of the pom file:

```
  [..]
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  [..]
```

Comment: not sure but one of the recent commits to neo4j-jdbc might have changed the behaviour to not show these messages.

Comment: You are referencing https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/commit/0efe988ac532f8162e9e42cf1644f73e114de417 "removed annoying outputs"? Nope, this addresses code where no logger was used :-)

Comment: I think I removed it lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stefan Armbruster and Michael Hunger mentioned in the comments it is fixed in the master branch.

I couldn't figure out exactly why the messages are send to the console, since it looks like a proper jcl logger is used, anyway the messages are gone in the 2.1.5-SNAPSHOT version.